# UIView.touchesMoved: locationInView always returns 0,0

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitouch, metal

This must be a silly mistake, but what could be the reason that `locationInView` always returns `(0.0, 0.0)` in my `ViewController`'s `touchesBegan` or `touchesMoved` method?

`userInteractionEnabled` is set to true, so this cannot be the reason..

I'm working on a Metal project in Swift. The only subview of the view is a `UIImageView` (whose `.image` property contains the result of the Metal GPU rendering.

**EDIT:** This happens on my iPhone 6 only, and it's happening in other projects too. On the simulator everything is working normally.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This went away at some time. Don't know, maybe it was a restart of the device.

Comment: It just happened for me on iPhone 8 Plus simulator (iOS 11) and restarting the device has solved the problem ! Thanks :)